# Is it possible to make a String[][] from a Map<String, String> using the Stream API?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

Is it possible to make a String[][] from HashMap by Stream API?

I try to get something like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("key1", "value1");
    map.put("key2", "value2");
    map.put("key3", "value3");   => 

 => String[][] 2dArray => [["key1", "value1"], ["key2", "value2"], ["key3", "value3"]]
```

I have made the same by simple java:

```
    Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entrySet = map.entrySet();

    String[][] result = new String[3][2];
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : entrySet){
            result[i][0] = entry.getKey();
            result[i][1] = entry.getValue();
            ++i;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can stream over the entry set of the `Map`, `map` each entry to an array that contains the key and the value, and convert that `Stream<String[]>` to a 2D array with `toArray()`.

```
String[][] arr = 
    map.entrySet()
       .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String,String>>
       .map(e -> new String[] {e.getKey(),e.getValue()}) // Stream<String[]>
       .toArray(String[][]::new); // String[][]
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString (arr));
```

Output:

```
[[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [key3, value3]]
```